# Dsolve gives linearly dependent solutions

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

I tried using Mathematica 11 to solve a Sturm-Liouville problem:

```
DSolve[{r f''[r] + f'[r] - r^3 f[r] + (4 k - 2 ) r f[r] == 0}, 
f[r], {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
Assumptions -> k \[Element] Integers && k <= 0]
```

But I got two linearly dependent solutions:

```
{{f[r] -> 
Sqrt[2] E^(r^2/2) (C[1] HypergeometricU[k, 1, -r^2] + C[2] LaguerreL[-k, -r^2])}}
```

(It is true that for non-negative integer values of a:

```
 LaguerreL[a , z] = C(a) HypergeometricU[-a, 1, z]
```

Where C(a) is some constant, so the solutions really are the same...)

I don't know if it is relevant, but this equation is a special case of a more complicated one from which I started, in which I got 2 linearly independent solutions, both of which converged to this identical solution above. That equation was:

```
DSolve[r f''[r] + f'[r] - b^2 r^-1 f[r] - r^3 f[r] + k r f[r] == 0,
f[r], {r, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

And it reduces to the problematic equation by taking b->0

What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions on negative `k` are not used.

You get same solution without the assumption (I think using assumptions with `DSolve` does not always go through, or are ignored), there are number of posts related to this.

```
DSolve[{r f''[r]+f'[r]-r^3 f[r]+(4 k-2) r f[r]==0},f[r],r,
         Assumptions->Element[k,Integers]&&k<=0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You get same solution without the assumption on `k`

```
DSolve[{r f''[r] + f'[r] - r^3 f[r] + (4 k - 2 ) r f[r] == 0}, f[r], r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To check for L.I. using the Wronskian

```
f1 = (Sqrt[2]*E^(r^2/2)*Sqrt[r^2]*HypergeometricU[k, 1, -r^2])/r
f2 = (Sqrt[2]*E^(r^2/2)*Sqrt[r^2]*LaguerreL[-k, -r^2])/r; 
mat = {{f1, f2}, {D[f1, r], D[f2, r]}}; 
w = Det[mat]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we can look at L.I. or not for different `k`.

```
 Plot[w /. k -> 1, {r, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Not zero. Hence L.I. for positive `k`.

```
  Plot[w /. k -> -1, {r, 0, 5}]
```

But for negative `k` they are L.D.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The whole point is that assumptions on `k` are not used when finding the solution.

Compare to Maple solution, which also behaves the same way, but in reverse. Maple gives two L.I. solutions for negative `k` but not for positive `k`.

Maple gives this solution to the ODE

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But the Wronskian is zero for positive `k` and non-zero for positive `k`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So if you want solution for negative `k`, use Maple's solution. For positive `k`, use Mathematica's solution.

Assumptions on `k` do not change the solution either in Maple, just like with Mathematica. So I do not think this is a bug.